# Split dataframe based on inline header

Tags: r, split, read.csv

I have a dataframe that is made up op multiple .csv files that are appended with `bind_rows`. My problem is that each csv file are stitched together and contains a different number of headers.
Each part of each csv file is seperated with a header line, that I would now like to split my df by.

An example of my df looks something like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| #HEADER |  |  |  |
| **Column A** | **Column C** | **Column E** |  |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 3 |  |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |  |

I would like to split my df every time I encouter a hashtag, which signifies a new "file" with a new set of headers.

Alternatively, I would like to read each csv file in parts based on the #header line. However, I do not know how to do this without it becoming overly complicated.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I tried reading each csv file separately based on the number of columns with a header title, my problem is that each csv file can itself contain multiple #Headers lines.

Likewise I tried a `group_split` approach, this was not possible as the unique ID is only defined in the #Header.

Comment: what about:  group_split(data, group = cumsum(`Column A` == "#HEADER")). ps sorry this formats weird because of the back tics around "Column A"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of splitting the data frame by the headers:

1. Create a new column for grouping the rows based on the headers.
2. Identify the rows that contain the `#HEADER` strings.
3. Enter different labels for different group of rows based on their respective labels.
4. Split the data frame by the group column. Store the results in a list.
5. Remove the group column in each data frame in the list.

For example, you have this data frame:

```
mydat = structure(list(V1 = c("Column A ", "Cell 1 ", "Cell 3 ", "-------- ", 
"HEADER_1", "Column A ", "Cell 3 ", "-------- ", "Column A ", 
"Cell 1 ", "Cell 3 ", "-------- ", "HEADER_2", "Column A ", "Cell 3 ", 
"-------- ", "Column A ", "Cell 1 ", "Cell 3 ", "-------- ", 
"HEADER_3", "Column A ", "Cell 3 ", "-------- "), V2 = c("Column B ", 
"Cell 2 ", "Cell 4 ", "-------- ", "", "Column C ", "Cell 4 ", 
"-------- ", "Column B ", "Cell 2 ", "Cell 4 ", "-------- ", 
"", "Column C ", "Cell 4 ", "-------- ", "Column B ", "Cell 2 ", 
"Cell 4 ", "-------- ", "", "Column C ", "Cell 4 ", "-------- "
), V3 = c("Column C ", "Cell 2 ", "Cell 3 ", "-------- ", "", 
"Column E ", "Cell 3 ", "-------- ", "Column C ", "Cell 2 ", 
"Cell 3 ", "-------- ", "", "Column E ", "Cell 3 ", "-------- ", 
"Column C ", "Cell 2 ", "Cell 3 ", "-------- ", "", "Column E ", 
"Cell 3 ", "-------- "), V4 = c("Column D", "Cell 2", "Cell 4", 
"--------", "", "", "", "", "Column D", "Cell 2", "Cell 4", "--------", 
"", "", "", "", "Column D", "Cell 2", "Cell 4", "--------", "", 
"", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")

mydat

#           V1        V2        V3       V4
# 1  Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
# 2    Cell 1    Cell 2    Cell 2    Cell 2
# 3    Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3    Cell 4
# 4  --------  --------  --------  --------
# 5   HEADER_1                             
# 6  Column A  Column C  Column E          
# 7    Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3          
# 8  --------  --------  --------          
# 9  Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
# 10   Cell 1    Cell 2    Cell 2    Cell 2
# 11   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3    Cell 4
# 12 --------  --------  --------  --------
# 13  HEADER_2                             
# 14 Column A  Column C  Column E          
# 15   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3          
# 16 --------  --------  --------          
# 17 Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
# 18   Cell 1    Cell 2    Cell 2    Cell 2
# 19   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3    Cell 4
# 20 --------  --------  --------  --------
# 21  HEADER_3                             
# 22 Column A  Column C  Column E          
# 23   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3          
# 24 --------  --------  --------
```

Apply the aforementioned steps:

```
mydat$group = NA
m = 0
for(k in 1:nrow(mydat)){
        if(any(grepl("HEADER", mydat[k,]))){
          m = m+1
          mydat$group[k] = m
        } else mydat$group[k] = m
}
split(mydat, ~group) |> lapply(subset, select = -group)
```

Here is the result:

```
# $`0`
#          V1        V2        V3       V4
# 1 Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
# 2   Cell 1    Cell 2    Cell 2    Cell 2
# 3   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3    Cell 4
# 4 --------  --------  --------  --------
# 
# $`1`
#           V1        V2        V3       V4
# 5   HEADER_1                             
# 6  Column A  Column C  Column E          
# 7    Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3          
# 8  --------  --------  --------          
# 9  Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
# 10   Cell 1    Cell 2    Cell 2    Cell 2
# 11   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3    Cell 4
# 12 --------  --------  --------  --------
# 
# $`2`
#           V1        V2        V3       V4
# 13  HEADER_2                             
# 14 Column A  Column C  Column E          
# 15   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3          
# 16 --------  --------  --------          
# 17 Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
# 18   Cell 1    Cell 2    Cell 2    Cell 2
# 19   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3    Cell 4
# 20 --------  --------  --------  --------
# 
# $`3`
#           V1        V2        V3 V4
# 21  HEADER_3                       
# 22 Column A  Column C  Column E    
# 23   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3    
# 24 --------  --------  --------
```

### EDIT

If you want to name the list elements with the headers, here is one of the ways to do that:

```
mydat$group = ""
m = "no_header"  # or anything
for(k in 1:nrow(mydat)){
        if(any(grepl("HEADER", mydat[k,]))){
          m = mydat[k,] |> unlist() |> paste(collapse = "")
          mydat$group[k] = m
        } else mydat$group[k] = m
}
split(mydat, ~group) |> lapply(subset, select = -group)
```

The result:

```
# $HEADER_1
#           V1        V2        V3       V4
# 5   HEADER_1                             
# 6  Column A  Column C  Column E          
# 7    Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3          
# 8  --------  --------  --------          
# 9  Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
# 10   Cell 1    Cell 2    Cell 2    Cell 2
# 11   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3    Cell 4
# 12 --------  --------  --------  --------
# 
# $HEADER_2
#           V1        V2        V3       V4
# 13  HEADER_2                             
# 14 Column A  Column C  Column E          
# 15   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3          
# 16 --------  --------  --------          
# 17 Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
# 18   Cell 1    Cell 2    Cell 2    Cell 2
# 19   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3    Cell 4
# 20 --------  --------  --------  --------
# 
# $HEADER_3
#           V1        V2        V3 V4
# 21  HEADER_3                       
# 22 Column A  Column C  Column E    
# 23   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3    
# 24 --------  --------  --------    
# 
# $no_header
#          V1        V2        V3       V4
# 1 Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
# 2   Cell 1    Cell 2    Cell 2    Cell 2
# 3   Cell 3    Cell 4    Cell 3    Cell 4
# 4 --------  --------  --------  --------
```

Comment: Great, it works! Is it possible to use the #Headers as list element names?

Comment: Yes, it is. Please check my edited answer.